# How to add an android test device to Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am integrating Firebase analytics in my android app but I cant see in documentation or google how I can add a test device so It doesn't count on stats.

I test a lot, so my main stats will be corrupted if it counts my own events

In admob I do

```
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("70A9E11F73EREFF712A1B73AE2BC2945")
            .addTestDevice("1D18F0345E4C90E3625DB344BE64D02E")
            .build();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add device with adb command:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app packageName
```

Comment: This is the correct method.
From the Firebase docs: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7201382?hl=en&utm_id=ad&authuser=0

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with a new audience in Firebase Console with filter:
User Properties / App Store + "does not contain" + "manual_install"

I figured it out that all direct app installs and also all Firebase Test Lab installs falls into this parameter.

If you want to remove only a few users then you could add this filter (haven't tried it):
User Properties / User ID + "not equal to" (or "does not contain") + your_ID

This only works in Firebase Analytics and only with events that happened after audience was created.

---

For BigQuery I use the following query to exclude the testing devices:

```
SELECT
  user_dim.user_id                                      AS userId,
  FORMAT_UTC_USEC(user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros) AS tsFirstOpen,
  user_dim.device_info.device_category                  AS dCaterogy,
  user_dim.device_info.mobile_brand_name                AS dBrand,
  user_dim.device_info.device_model                     AS dModel2,
  user_dim.device_info.platform_version                 AS dOSver,
  user_dim.device_info.user_default_language            AS dDefLanguage,
  user_dim.geo_info.continent                           AS geoCont,
  user_dim.geo_info.country                             AS geoCounty,
  user_dim.app_info.app_version                         AS appVer,

FROM 
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE(YOUR_TABLE_NAME.app_events_, TIMESTAMP('2016-06-23'), TIMESTAMP('2016-10-01'))
WHERE
// Remove all testing devices
  NOT (user_dim.user_id == "YOUR_USER_ID" OR 
       user_dim.user_id == "YOUR_USER_ID") AND
  NOT user_dim.app_info.app_store == "manual_install"  AND
  user_dim.user_properties.key == "first_open_time"

GROUP BY
  tsFirstOpen,
  userId,
  dCaterogy,
  dBrand,
  dModel2,
  dOSver,
  dDefLanguage,
  geoCont,
  geoCounty,
  appVer
ORDER BY
  appVer DESC,
  tsFirstOpen DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This is very usefull, however, I will like to prevent the test devices sending the data!

Comment: @D4rWiNS: Maybe [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(boolean)) is what you want? Just found it today when looking for something else :).

Comment: Grah thx for the info! It is another way to do it, I am actually using your method of manually install