# How to ignore firebase events coming from specific devices?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm logging events on my Android app, while testing those events gets triggered and thus visible on the console.

How do I ensure that Firebase considers my device as a "test device" and does not consider it in the console?

This is with Firebase Analytics

Comment: did u detach the listener and tried??

Comment: @Roy How to detach the listener?

Comment: this might help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631533/how-to-add-an-android-test-device-to-firebase